# python map function error

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to convert all the numbers in a list to their squares using a lambda function and map function,but it doesn't seem to gimme the correct output! Here is the code:

```
num_file = [12,24,36]
map(lambda num:num**2,num_file)
```

But it gives me this output instead of the squares :

```
<map at 0x4d82d10>
```

please Help !

Comment: just apply `list` on it : `list(map(lambda num:num**2,num_file))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` returns a map object, to get a list out of it, use the `list` function:

```
>>> num_file = [12,24,36]
>>> list(map(lambda num:num**2,num_file))
[144, 576, 1296]
```

You can  also use a list comprehension:

```
>>> num_file = [12,24,36]
>>> [num**2 for num in num_file]
[144, 576, 1296]
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to help :).

Answer (score 2):

`map` returns a generator. If you want to get an actual list do `list(map(..))`.

Note that you often don't want to do it explicitly.

For example next code will work just fine:

```
for square in map(lambda n: n**2, [12, 24, 36]):
    print(square)
```